# How to call acknowledgment functions in SocketIO?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Following the documentation on the [SocketIO website](https://socket.io/docs/), I have the following code:

**Server**

```
socket.on('foo', (arg, ack) => {
    //Do stuff with arg
    if(ack)
        ack('response');
});
```

**Client**

```
socket.emit('foo', arg, (response) => {
    console.log(response);
});
```

However, the `ack` function is never called. As a matter of fact, it is `undefined`. I am using SocketIO v2.0.4 on both server and client side.

Am I missing something? The docs make it look like it should be that easy, yet I just can't figure it out!

Thanks!

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: @bugwheels94, I just tested it with Socket 2.04 and it works for me. See this repo https://github.com/tarunlalwani/socket.io-stackoverflow-47983512

Comment: @TarunLalwani It works but my code and probably OP's code is still not working. I have seen few other question same as this on SO. Looks like something else is doing that maybe. Looking into the issue if there is any

Comment: Then you need to provide a minimal repo on which I can reproduce this, else it won't help. The only other issue could be you are using a wrong client js. I saw similar issue when I had used `socket.js` on client side from a CDN and my server version was upgraded to a different version

Comment: @TarunLalwani That is the problem. Minimal example is working. I am checking with namespace and other things etc. if there is any problem. You may post your efforts as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue usually occurs when you have a mismatch between the `socket.io` version and `socket.io.js` version. That is one scenario in which I was able to reproduce the `ack` being undefined.

Other I just tested it with Socket 2.04 and it works fine.

**index.js**

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var host = process.env.HOST || "0.0.0.0";

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  console.log(' request received ', req.headers.host);
  res.status(200).send();
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });

socket.on('ferret', function (name, fn) {
    console.log('name', name, 'fn', fn);
    fn('tarun');
  });
});

http.listen(port,host, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:' + port);
  console.log('Env name is ' + process.env.name)
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
      #messages { margin-bottom: 40px }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {
        var socket = io();
socket.on('connect', function () { // TIP: you can avoid listening on `connect` and listen on events directly too!
    socket.emit('ferret', 'tobi', function (data) {
      console.log(data); // data will be 'woot'
    });
  });
        $('form').submit(function(){
          socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
          $('#m').val('');
          return false;
        });
        socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
          $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
          window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
        });

      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "socket-chat-example",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "my first socket.io app",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "socket.io": "^2.0.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  }
}
```

[image: Working]

Answer (score 13):

Server side

```
var io = require('socket.io')(8090);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('connected')
  socket.on('ferret', function (arg, ack) {
    console.log('ferret')
    ack('woot');
  });
});
```

Client side

```
const ioClient = require('socket.io-client');
var client = ioClient.connect('http://localhost:8090');
client.emit('ferret', 'tobu', (response) => {
  console.log(response)
  console.log('ack')
});
```

It will log the response of ack() and the 'ack' string. I got the reference [socket.io acknowledge node.js sample](https://gist.github.com/capaj/d9fb9660f49d15fc8319d3f310e77c0a).

Answer (score 1):

Server

```
socket.on('foo', (arg) => {
//Do stuff with arg
    console.log('message from client : ' + data)
    socket.emit('bar','message acknowledge from server');
});
```

Client

```
socket.emit('foo', 'mymessage');
socket.on('bar', (data) => {
    console.log(data)
});
```

using `socket.io` in server side and `socket.io-client` in client side

Server side

```
var app = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(app);

app.listen(80);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' }, function(res) {
        console.log(res);
    });
});
```

Client side

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');

var socket = io('http://localhost');
socket.on('news', function (data, ack) {
    console.log(data);
    if(ack){
        ack("acknowledge from client");
    }
});
```

Comment: Well, yeah. That's how I'm doing it now. But allegedly there is built-in functionality as I described above.

Comment: try to browse the `socket.io` in node_module maybe you need to use the `socket.io-client` module.. I try it it my local and it's working the `ack`

Comment: You have basically copy pasted the question and called it an answer

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't looked at this issue in a while, but just the other day I updated all of the SocketIO dependencies for both client and server, and it worked exactly as expected.

Not sure what the specific issue was, but it seems to be working as documented now.

Thanks all for the input!

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple, keep the last argument of any `.emit` from a client as `callback` function. and call this callback `fn` from server listener.

Official doc is [here](https://socket.io/docs/#Sending-and-getting-data-acknowledgements)

#### Server.js

```
var io = require('socket.io')(80);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('ferret', function (name, fn) {
    fn('woot');
  });
});
```

#### Client.js

```
<script>
  var socket = io(); // TIP: io() with no args does auto-discovery
  socket.on('connect', function () { // TIP: you can avoid listening on `connect` and listen on events directly too!
    socket.emit('ferret', 'tobi', function (data) {
      console.log(data); // data will be 'woot'
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well and I found the issue. It is is a little embarrassing to admit, but I had a mismatch of the number of arguments passed to socket.emit() and socket.on():

```
// server
socket.on('myEvent', (payload, callback) => { ... })

// client
socket.emit('myEvent', callback)
```

Notice, how I didn't supply "payload" to the emit call... This resulted in "callback" to be undefined on the server.

Answer (score 0):

### Simple ack wrapper with proper error handling

This feature is severely under-documented.

[From looking at the source code](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/master/lib/socket.ts#L171), it appears that `acks` are not properly taken care of in the face of errors. That is why my `socket` wrapper has a `sendWithAck` function like so:

```js
class ClientSocket {
  _socket;

  // ...
  
  sendWithAck(msg, data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this._socket.once('error', reject);
      this._socket.emit(msg, data, resolve);
    });
  }
}
```

You can use it like so:

```js
try {
  const ackResult = await sendWithAck('mydata', { x: 3 });
  console.log('ack received:', ackResult);
}
catch (err) {
  console.error('error happened before ack was received', err);
}
```

NOTE: This works on both, client and server.