# How to listen to an event after emitting an event Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I want to build an SQL handler server side on my nodejs server.

I would like my nodejs to recieve requests from client side - for example :

client.js

```
socket.emit("sql-query", "SELECT * FROM *");
socket.on('sql-response', results => {
    do things with results...
}
```

server.js

```
socket.on('sql-query', query => {
    connection.query(query, function(error, results, fields)) {
        if(results > 0) socket.emit('sql-response', results);
        else console.log('No results... yet !');
    }
});
```

Problem is, if I do that, every function that needs to make an SQL request will get the sql-response event.

I would want my emit to return results without having to catch another event (that every file using SQL request will catch).

Something like this :
server.js

```
socket.on('sql-query', query => {
    connection.query(query, function(error, results, fields)) {
        if(results > 0) socket.return(results); //I know this is wrong and that's not how events work.
    }
});
```

General idea : Make SQL requests using a nodejs / socket.io server from other files.

Please tell me if it's a headache to do that and if there is another better way of achieving this.

Thank you

Comment: *Please tell me if it's a headache to do*, not really, but the SQL injections will hurt more. You can use acknowledgement callbacks i.e [`socket.emit(eventName[, …args][, ack]);`](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-api/#socketemiteventname-args-ack), [dupe/examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47983512/how-to-call-acknowledgment-functions-in-socketio) no need for `socket.on('sql-response'`

Comment: Damn thank you. This is exactly what I needed, 
client.emit('ferret', 'tobu', (response) => {
  console.log(response)
  console.log('ack')
});

Did not know you could wait for a response in the emit itself. Thank you again

Comment: np, don't forget to check its a function before invoking i.e `if (typeof ack === 'function') ack(result)`,  the dupe answers in the link don't address it, if it's not a func and called it would crash the server

Answer (score 0):

I am not pretty sure If I got you, but for me, it works as you want, but it is the same code that you are using, because socket.emit does not multicast

Server

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('sql-query', (query) => {
    socket.emit('sql-response', `this is your response: ${query}`);
  });
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Client

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      body { margin: 0; padding-bottom: 3rem; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }

      #form { background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15); padding: 0.25rem; position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; display: flex; height: 3rem; box-sizing: border-box; backdrop-filter: blur(10px); }
      #input { border: none; padding: 0 1rem; flex-grow: 1; border-radius: 2rem; margin: 0.25rem; }
      #input:focus { outline: none; }
      #form > button { background: #333; border: none; padding: 0 1rem; margin: 0.25rem; border-radius: 3px; outline: none; color: #fff; }

      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages > li { padding: 0.5rem 1rem; }
      #messages > li:nth-child(odd) { background: #efefef; }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.0.1/socket.io.js" integrity="sha512-q/dWJ3kcmjBLU4Qc47E4A9kTB4m3wuTY7vkFJDTZKjTs8jhyGQnaUrxa0Ytd0ssMZhbNua9hE+E7Qv1j+DyZwA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form id="form" action="">
      <input id="input" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
  </body>
  <script>
    var socket = io();
    var form = document.getElementById('form');
    var input = document.getElementById('input');

    form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (input.value) {
        console.log(input.value)
        socket.emit('sql-query', input.value);
        input.value = '';
      }
    });

    socket.on('sql-response', function(msg) {
      var item = document.createElement('li');
      item.textContent = msg;
      messages.appendChild(item);
      window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm sorry I wrote this so bad. Even after re-reading it myself I couldn't get it.
Imagine I have two functions. A log in, which checks in a table with a SELECT SQL query. And a register, which includes an INSERT SQL query. I have two pages, login and register. Both emit different SQL Queries. But both catch the event "sql-response". How can I make it so only the emitting function recieves the sql-response ?

Comment: No problem, I created an example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-moon-wyfub), this example has two views **login** and **register**, both contain the same code, but in this example you can see that the login view receive that it sent and in the same way the register view, please tell me if I didn’t get you.